# Enable SSL for custom domains in App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-app-engine-python

I'm using app engine standard with `python` I added custom domain in app engine `api.octabyte.io` and a wildcard `*.api.octabyte.io`

I have two services `default` and `quran` I'm able to access both services like this.

default -> `api.octabyte.io`
quran -> `quran.api.octabyte.io/v1/docs`

SSL work fine for default service `https://api.octabyte.io` but not with `quran` service `https://quran.api.octabyte.io`

Can you please let me know how can I enable **SSL** for other services.

You can access `quran` service with **SSL** when you use default url of app engine
 `https://quran-dot-islam786.appspot.com/v1/docs`

Here is screenshot of custom domains in app engine
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google-managed SSL certificates don't support wildcard mappings: [Upgrading to managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#upgrading_to_managed_ssl_certificates)